# Pointer nuances? "Free heap block modified after it was freed"

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-corruption

I was under the impression that in order to use delete (or delete[]), I only need to provide the address and the object type. So for example, suppose I have 10 objects of class MyClass at memory address x. I also have a global (void*) vPtr. Some time ago this happened

```
 vPtr = (void*)(myClassPtr);
```

At some further point in time, those objects were no longer needed, and I wish to use that memory to store different objects, so I call

```
delete[] (myClass*)(vPtr);
```

This executes just fine. Then I go about creating my new objects and reassigning vPtr to their address

```
MyClass* myPtr2 = new MyClass[10];
vPtr = (void*)(myPtr2);
```

Now, once I'm done using the 10 MyClass objects, I wish to repurpose the memory they were using for more different objects. So I call:

```
delete[] (MyClass*)(vPtr);    //just like before, but this time, VS2010 breaks
                                //and complains about heap corruption
```

What am I missing? The memory trying to be freed by delete[] **has** to be occupied by my 10 MyClass objects, so why would there be a heap corruption? I am doubly confused because I am using this same method on objects of class MyFoo, and when I step through the code, reassigning my (void*) pointer and calling delete[] each time I wish to release the memory and create new objects, I *never* get complaints of heap corruption.

Comment: Do you mean to use `vPtr` in your last code snippet or is `myPtr2` correct?

Comment: Also, could you make a tiny example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: fixed! I'll see if I can come up with a short example

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. Heap corruption is a shared problem among all parts of a program that allocate memory. A bug in one module can show up as a crash in another.

Comment: The `delete` that you have shown is fine. The symptom probably indicates you have caused heap corruption elsewhere in your code. You could try "valgrind".